# Failed to stop mysql-server.service: Unit mysql-server.service not loaded

Tags: mysql, linux-server

I'm getting a weird error when trying to stop mysql-server with the `service` command:

```
$ sudo service mysql-server stop
Failed to stop mysql-server.service: Unit mysql-server.service not loaded.
```

Is `service` at fault here, or is it mysql? How to figure out what's the problem? This is ubuntu 16.04.

Doing it directly via its script in `/etc/init.d/` seems to work:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
[sudo] password for myuser: 
[ ok ] Stopping mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.
```

Why does `service` not work anymore here?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this command?:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

If you need to run:

```
 sudo service mysql start
```